# MonetaryAmount from Schema.org - How to avoid floating point issues?

Tags: floating-point, schema.org, currency, json-ld

It is bad practice to represent money using double or float, because these are not precise, and the rounding errors could cause a problem. So a common practice is to use an integer with the smaller unit of currency -- e.g. to write 100c instead of $1, or 100p instead of £1.

However `MonetaryAmount` in Schema.org suggests a number such as 1.00.

If I make a JSON object for $1.50 such as:

```json
{
    "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
    "currency": "USD",
    "value": 1.50    
}
```

And store that in a JSON-based object store, then it's going to be handled as a floating point. If I x100 to get an integer, then I'm not following Schema.org.

What is best practice here? Is there a way to both follow Schema.org and avoid a floating point number?